# getting swatches js css error

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have implemented swatches for simple products and configurable products. it includes color, prices, size. when I access the products page, I am getting failed to load resource: (some js, CSS files). swatches related CSS and js are present in skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches. My custom theme is customTheme. This configurableswatches folder is not present in my custom theme. I have attached screenshot of bug.

[image]

I do not want this errors in console.

Comment: Add folder "configurableswatches" in skin/frontend/customTheme/default/js/configurableswatches

or 

skin/frontend/base/default/js/configurableswatches

Comment: I have added some configurable swatches files from rwd to custom theme. is it necessary to add css and js files to my skin/frontend/customtheme/js and skin/frontend/customtheme/css folder.